# Passing the results of a select statement as parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that does various checks and inserts values to multiple tables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedprocedurename] 
    @Parameter1 uniqueidentifier,
    @Parameter2 datetime2,
    @Parameter3 bit,
    @Parameter4 varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Parameter IS NULL
    THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
```

I also have a select statement that returns about 600 rows.

```
SELECT 
    column1, column2, column3, column4 
FROM
    Table1
```

Output:

```
         Column1              Column2         Column3          Column 4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        ared-234w-5yhe       12/07/2020         0             Table       
2        fjed-reds-sdfg       10/10/1989         1             Chair      
3        fgsv-34yg-jtut       1/4/1965           1             Computer
```

I basically want my stored procedure to fetch the values from the select statement, input them as parameters and execute. Essentially it will run about 600 times or based on the number of rows of the select.

```
EXEC [dbo].[storedprocedurename] 'ared-234w-5yhe', '12/07/2020', 0, 'Table'
EXEC [dbo].[storedprocedurename] 'fjed-reds-sdfg', '10/10/1989', 1, 'Chair'
```

How can I do this? I am using SQL Server

Comment: Erland has a good discussion on [arrays and lists](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html). Follow that with his discusson on [using TVPs](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Answer (score 2):

The straighforward option is to use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @column1 uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @column2 datetime2
DECLARE @column3 bit
DECLARE @column4 varchar(max)

DECLARE cur_Table1 CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 FROM dbo.Table1

OPEN cur_Table1  
  
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Table1
      INTO @column1, @column2, @column3, @column4
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    EXEC dbo.storedprocedurename @column1, @column2, @column3, @column4

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Table1   
          INTO @column1, @column2, @column3, @column4 
END   

CLOSE cur_Table1;  
DEALLOCATE cur_Table1;
```

However, you usually can find a SET based alternative is more adequate for SQL that the procedural ones.

In that case you would put aside the stored procedure and all the logic for the parameters should be SET based. For example for the stored procedure you shared it might be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
    SELECT NEWID(), column2, column3, column4
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS T1
    WHERE T1.column1 IS NULL
```

I guess that you were thinking of a more elaborated logic, so, if you want to share we can take a look and tell you how to convert it. Sometimes it's easy and sometimes it's not and the result is not easy to understand. In that case you should evaluate the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: @DDLearn - did this answer help you?